# "Not authorized to perform operation" accesing to a flash drive when logged in Kubuntu 22.04 only with numeric usernames of our LDAP

Tags: kubuntu, authentication, plasma, ldap

I've configured Kubuntu 22.04 with pam-ldap following:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication

After configuring ldap authentication, if I login in with a text username like "sczabcde", all works well. But if i login with a numerical username like "87254901" i login well, and i can work, but i can't access to USB drives. When i click into an external USB drive in dolphin, y get a message "Not authorized to perform operation".

I have added all groups of an usual kubuntu user in /etc/security/group.conf , and with an text based username all works (i can mount USB drives), but with numeric usernames i can't access to USB drives.

Thanks in advantage, aitor

Comment: I have "resolved" doing a mapping between username and email. If in ldap.conf you add this lines:
`nss_map_attribute cn mail`
`pam_login_attribute mail`
`nss_map_attribute uid mail`

Comment: If you change this your users will need to access  with their email and password instead with their username and password

Comment: Usefull: https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux

Comment: The problem of this is that then you can't do a login in a console. ¿More ideas?